# Building EOS on Ubuntu Linux Subsystem

Tags: nodeos, ubuntu, build, boost

I am having some issues running eosio_build.sh on Ubuntu 16.04 which is running on Windows 10 through the linux subsystem. It installs all the dependencies but stalls when installing the boost libraries and doesn't continue to build. Here is a screenshot of the terminal.

[image: EOS failed build]

Answer (score 1):

You will probably be better off installing boot manually.  That is what I had to do https://www.boost.org/:

## Install the required packages

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential g++ python-dev autotools-dev libicu-dev build-essential libbz2-dev
```

## Install the Boost libraries

```
wget -O boost.tar.gz https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.67.0/source/boost_1_67_0.tar.gz
tar xzvf boost.tar.gz
cd boost_1_67_0
```

## Boost bootstrap setup:

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/
```

## Then build it with:

```
./b2
```

## install it:

```
sudo ./b2 install
```

Comment: After trying your fix it still stalls after trying to download the boost library. Could it be that it is searching for boost in usr/opt/boost instead of usr/lib? If so how can i change this?

Answer (score 1):

Used [Thomas5577's instructions](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/1993/961) but created an `opt` directory in `/usr/` and then a `boost` directory within `opt`. Then I installed the `boost` library, but I changed the bootstrap setup command to `./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/opt/boost`, and the eosio build worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
./eosio_build.sh # no sudo for build
sudo ./eosio_install.sh
```

I had similar problems with WSL 16.04.

Using the 18.04 image brought up better results.

Note that I finally did not manage to stabilize the eos-tests on WSL, and switched to a VirtualBox 18.04.

WSL is currently unsupported by the team.